# Can't center in html/css

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, margin, centering

This code should work (in my opinion) but, I ca't figure out why it won't. Thanks in advance

```
<body>
<div id="wrap">
<div style="margin:auto;"><img src="logo.png" alt="logo"/></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**
I'm trying to center it. It stays in the upper left hand corner. Adding a height and width of auto to both divs also did not work.

Comment: in which  browser and which version???

Comment: What about it "doesn't work"? How is anyone going to help you if you don't say what you want your code to actually do?

Comment: As the title says "Can't center"

It stays in the default upper left hand corner of the screen. I just want the logo.png to center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to check 2 things before you set your division's to center.

1. Doctype : check whether it is not in quirks mode.
2. Width of inner div must me less that width of parent div.

do check these things you will get your answer...All the best.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to horizontally center the logo then you have to also specify the width of the containing div. Here is a sample code.

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
<div style="width:100px; margin:0 auto;"><img src="logo.png" alt="logo"/></div>
</div>
</body>
</html?
```

Answer (score 1):

The inner div must have a set width for the margin auto to work.

Answer (score 0):

Is the width of the inner div less than the width of the #wrap div?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that the wrap has a set width, the div holding the image will need a set width as well.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jtwebb/b7SBN/) so you can see that it does work. (a bit overkill for this question, I know :) )